# How to set the value of a Date field to the current date time in this Oracle DB table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-update, sysdate

I am pretty new with DB and I have the following problem trying to update a **Date** field into a table definied on an Oracle DB.

So in my DB I have a table named **CERTIFICAZIONI** that have a **Date** field named **DATA_VISUALIZZAZIONE**.

I have to create a query that update the **DATA_VISUALIZZAZIONE** with the current date time.

So I am trying to do something like this:

```
UPDATE certificazione SET data_visualizzazione=??? WHERE ID=1
```

I think that the main structure of the query is right but I don't know how to set the current date time to this field. How can I do this?

Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `systimestamp` or `sysdate` for this based on your need, like below

```
UPDATE certificazione SET data_visualizzazione=systimestamp WHERE ID=1;
```

or

```
UPDATE certificazione SET data_visualizzazione=sysdate WHERE ID=1
```

will make the give such details about date,time and timezone.

Comment: For a `DATE` column, you should better use `SYSDATE`. This avoids an implicite cast. Timezone and fractional seconds are truncated in `DATE`

Comment: @Wernfried yes you are correct. If you need additional details you can use `systimestamp` else use `sysdate`

Answer (score 0):

Given that the **data type** is **DATE**, you could set the column with **SYSDATE** value. It will have both date and time portions.

```
UPDATE certificazione 
SET    data_visualizzazione = SYSDATE 
WHERE  id = 1;
```